# Robot Framework: Connected to a server via SSH library now need to telnet to a ip from this ssh. Any one has any clue of this

Tags: python-2.7, ssh, robotframework

Here is the sample code. Robot Framework: Connected to a server via SSH library now need to telnet to a ip from this ssh. Any one has any clue of this?

We are able to login through ssh to server now need to telnet from this server to an ips using  ssh library

```
*** Settings ***
Library     SSHLibrary

*** Variables ***

${HOST}         IP
${HOST_USERNAME}    uname
${HOST_PASSWORD}    pwd


*** Test Cases ***
${id}=  Open Connection     host=${HOST}    alias=s1
${output}=  Login           ${HOST_USERNAME}    ${HOST_PASSWORD}

${sid}= Execute Command telnet ipaddr
Write   password
```

Comment: What is the issue you are having?

Comment: Issue: 
Robot Framework runs on machine A. The test connects A to machine B via ssh and B to machine C via telnet.

Is there a way to use telnet within an ssh connection in Robot Framework? Could you please suggest me. 

Now we are able to connect through SSH by using below Robot(Python) script. The issue is with telnet within an ssh connection. We are not able to connect through telnet within an SSH.

We are able to run commands using this  "Execute Command" but validation part is the one struck point here.

Comment: now i am able to connect to telnet session but unable to send password Read ${out}= Execute Command telnet ip-address is the command used and sample output is 18:28:40.829 INFO ${out} = Trying 192.168.56.57...
Connected to 192.168.56.57 (192.168.56.57).
Escape character is '^]'.


Password :

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Telnet](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/libraries/Telnet.html?r=2.8.5) test library which you can use for that purpose